# Increase size of mat-select but not change mat-form-field?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to increase the size of the mat-select options without changing the size of the mat-form-field. It currently looks like this:

[image]

But when I try to change the size of the mat-select it pushes the arrow across and into the next field:

[image]

Code:

```
<mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>Account Name</mat-label>
                    <mat-select
                        id="account_list"
                        ngDefaultControl
                        formControlName="account"
                        class="menu-size"
                    >
                        <mat-option
                            *ngFor="let acc of accounts; let i = index"
                            [value]="acc.name"
                            id="account_option_{{ i }}"
                        >
                            {{ acc.name }}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

CSS:

```
 .menu-size {
            width: 350px;
        }
```

Is there a way to increase the size of the mat options menu without effecting the mat form field?

Comment: Please create an output (live example) for people to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you're after using [CSS Flex Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). Reading a full article can be overwhelming, so I usually use an [online tool](https://flexbox.buildwithreact.com/) to help me so I can quickly visualize what I'm after and grab the required css styles.

Using the code below I was able to make the select menu take up the remaining empty space after I resize the `amount` input to 100px:

```
<div class="flex-container" style="display: flex;">

  <mat-form-field class="flex-fill-empty-space" style="flex: 1 1 auto">
    <mat-label>Account Name</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let acc of [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }]">{{ acc.name }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="flex-stay-original-size" style="flex: 0 1 auto; width: 100px; margin-left: 1em;">
    <mat-label>Amount</mat-label>
    <input matInput>
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

Example Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taking the example of Juan, I need use 2 selects in the same row, and I modify a few lines to implement the modification, it works:

After:

[image]

Before: taking full width of the column

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="flex-container d-flex">
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="flex-fill-empty-space" style="flex: 1 1 auto">
    <mat-label>Account Name</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.value">
          {{year.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>

 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="flex-stay-original-size ms-4 w-auto" style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
   <mat-label>Account Name</mat-label>
     <mat-select>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.value">
         {{year.viewValue}}
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```